# Visual Studio 2017 application doesn't run in another computer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version

I've seen that there is a lot of literature about this topic, but nothing specific to VS2017.

I've created an application that works properly on my PC, but when i move it to another one it doesn't start at all.

I've tried to install the latest version of .Net Framework (4.7.1) but it looks like the new pc doesn't recognize it. In the framework folder below directory reference assemblies it's missing, only 3.0 and 3.5 are available.

I have seen that there is another method to let the application run: static linking of dll. But I didn't find the way to do it with VS2017. There isn't section c++\c where flag /mt instead of /md. I know that my application will be larger, but I don't mind.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't start at all"?  Are you getting an error message?  Does nothing happen at all?  Does something happen, but not what you expect?  You say you installed the latest version of .Net Framework, but what version are you targeting with the application?

Comment: Hi Teagost, i don't get any error message. From the activities manager i see that the application starts but the it closes by itself after a couple of seconds. I have 2 laptops, one with windows 8 where i don't get any error message, the other with window 7 where i get a message like the program will be close and it shows some details (i don't remeber it very well sibce i have the laptops in my office). I've targetted my version with .netframework 4.5.

Comment: The latest version that i can target is 4.6.1, all versions from 4.0 to 4.6.1 have been installed by visual studio 2017, while versions 3.0 and 3.5 where native with my pc.

Comment: That typically happens in Windows 7 when there's an unhandled exception, you may want to look through your exception handling and put in some logging to track down the problem

Comment: Ok, but on my computer, where i've developed my application, there is windows 7 and it doesn't show me any unhandled exception. The other strange thing that came to me was that i've made other 2 beta versions before this one, and both of them were working properly on the other computers. In the code i've added the comand zipfile and i had to flag something for let it work. Could be this component that gives the problem? This is a test that i'd like to do on Monday back to office.

Comment: If you mean that you're calling an external zip program, it very well could be.  You really need to look through your code and see where you can improve the exception handling, I'm pretty sure there's an error out there that will tell you what the problem is, but you're unable to see it.  Maybe check the Event Viewer logs on the machines that it's crashing on?

Comment: Ok i'll try to do it, but how? Could you tell me how to do it? Cheers

Comment: Any way i'm not calling an external zip program, i've added library system.io.compression and the command zipfile. I think that it's something internal and available in the VS2017 libraries.

Comment: Still looking for a solution today i've read something about the dlls path. Probably Teagost are right and there is an unhandled exception that closes my application, but i think that the problem is due to the fact that in the other computers the application is pointing to an unexisting dll path since in the reference assemblies folder i don't have the framework folder about net 4.5. On Monday i'll copy the same path from my pc to the laptop and see what happens. Maybe it's not politically correct from software point of view, but do you think that it will work?

Comment: At the end i've found the problem. In my application there were some wrong relative path that they were causing some exceptions. I coukd see it with event viewer as suggested by Taegost. Thanks